# Using a login shell only for the :term command

Tags: bash, terminal-buffer

I'm on MacOS, so basically all terminals are login terminals for me which source my `bash_profile` and load everything I need.

However, the `:term` command does not source my `bash_profile`, I believe because its not a login terminal.

I know I can use `set shell=bash\ -l` to do this, but that also causes Vim to source my `bash_profile` on load, which is slow.

Is there a way to only do this when actually running the `term` command in Vim?

**Update Solved!**

[Ralf](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/19763/ralf)'s idea worked perfectly. I also integrated in [d-ben-knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble)'s interactive check as well.

```
if [[ -n "$PS1" && -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]]; then
    source "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this in bash:

1) Move all setting that you need in login shells *and* non-login shells to the file `.bashrc`

2) Add the following to the end of your `.bash_profile`:

```
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

You could drop the `if...`, as the file always exists.

Background: The file `.bashrc` is source by bash if it is started as an interactive shell that is not a login shell. See `man bash` section "INVOCATION".

---

You `.bash_profile` will be rather empty, but that is ok. On Linux I use the file `.profile` (sourced by bash if `.bash_profile` is not available) and it only contains a few `export` statements and the source command for `.bashrc`.

Comment: I would additionally include a test for the interactive flag

Comment: This works perfectly. I combined the original answer plus an interactive check as well, good idea!